# How to Add Location Pinpoint to MapView in Android

Tags: android, location, android-mapview

been scouring Google for hours and the Android docs to no avail. I have successfully got a map view to display, but need to add a location pinpoint button in the upper-right corner of the map view (as seen in the official Android maps app). I am looking for code samples as I am very new to the whole Android world.

Coming from iOS so it is rather shocking to see that there is little to no help with regard to this. I am thinking it is either dead simple and is something I am missing, or not possible...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the old (v1) Maps API or the newer Maps v2 API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using v2, then all you need to do is add:

```
getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

in your `onViewCreated()` method (add it at the end).

Comment: Hmmm... I don't believe I am using version 2, possible to point me to a good resource on how to utilize it? Google's documentation is sub-par and still points you to the docs for the deprecated maps view. Just to clarify, this call will create a button for me, not the current location dot, right? As I need something the user can press in order for the location to be shown, I don't want it always showing.

Comment: When you said upper right corner, are you talking about the ActionBar menu item? getMap().setMyLocationEnabled(true); gives you a button with a gps icon on top of the view. If you don't find the documentation helpful, you can download the Map samples from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro and try them.